# Can i use robotium for my test application?

Tags: robotium

I am having .apk (which is in beta version i.e it is our application's apk) which did not go to Android Market..

can i use robotium for testing the test environment apk or only the android market apk? I dont have the source code..

Thanks
Chandra

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You just need to make sure that your test application has the same signature as your AUT. Here is the documentation for that: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to sign it with a new signature using your own keystore. To get the source code, you need to use java decompiler, and APK tool.